# Editing/fixing mispelled custom type in places menu of Gramps?

Tags: gramps, renaming-places

In Gramps places, there is a place type that can be selected.

There was no place type named Cemetery so I added it. But in typing it in I typed it as `Cemetary`. I have added the correctly spelled place type `Cemetery` but am not able to delete the misspelled place type `Cemetary`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Your question here is well focussed, and hopefully will attract a potential answerer from amongst our Gramps users, quite quickly.

Answer (score 5):

You can, but it is a bit convoluted:

1. Export your tree in Gramps XML
2. Change the extension from .gramps to .gz
3. Unzip the file
4. Edit the XML to remove the misspelled type
5. Save the file
6. Rename it back to .gramps
7. Import the file into a new tree

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response Doug. This was very helpful information. I had already created the new correct place type "Cemetery" and used it in place of where I had used the incorrect Place Type "Cemetary". Therefore I could not find any of the incorrect instances in data.gramps xml file. But when I created a new database as you suggested and imported the data.gramps file into it, I found that the misspelled place type "Cemetary" was gone. Evidently creating a new database resets to the default place types and only uses them and any newly created place types in the data.gramps file.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Glad that you were able to fix it!